GA4 Google analytics : trouble showing user activity in User Explorer GA4 using custom user ID
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with displaying user activity in User Explorer GA4 when using a custom user ID. Here's the problem scenario:
When I use a custom user ID to identify users, they show up in the User Explorer.
However, when attempting to display their activity, I receive a "not found" error.
Interestingly, when I use the app instance ID instead of a custom user ID, the activity is displayed without any issues.

when i click on email :

but on app instance id it works ..
